# Reading metadata CSV from a datalake, too big for a lookup activity

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I need to create a pipeline to read CSVs from a folder, load from Row 8 into an Azure SQL table, Frist 5 rows will go into a different table ([tblMetadata]).

So far I have done it using Lookup Activity, works fine, but one of the files is bigger than 6 MB and it fails.

I checked all options in Lookup, read everything about Copy Activity (which I am using to load main data - skip 7 rows). The pipeline is created using GUI.

The output from the Lookup is used as parameters for a Stored Procedure to insert into tblMetadata

Can someone advise me how to deal with this? At the moment I am on the training, no one can help me on site.

Comment: Lookup active has the limits:The largest number of rows that can be returned by Lookup activity is 5,000, up to 2 MB in size.  How many csv files you have and what's the size of them?

Comment: Csv number will be dynamic, expecting more than 5 MB as already have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did workaround in different way, modified CSVs that are bing imported to have whole Metadata in the first row (as this was part of my different project). Then used FirstRow only in Lookup.

Comment: Hi @Baczek, you can accept(mark) it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do this with a single Data Flow activity that has a couple of transformations.

You would use a Source transformation that reads from a folder using folder paths and wildcards, then add a conditional split transformation to send different rows to different sinks.